# Loading models from .js files in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have tried plenty of multiple codes found on the internet but it always ends with black screen. 
Example code (the one that looks the most promising):

```js
var loader = new THREE.LegacyJSONLoader();

loader.load( 'resources/horse.js', function( geometry ) {
   var horse1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
   horse1.scale.set( 0.03, 0.03, 0.03 );
   horse1.position.y = 0;
   horse1.position.x = -9;
   horse1.position.z = 2.2;
   scene.add(horse1);
});
```

As i said, with that code fragment whole canvas turns black. I have no idea what to do at this point. Its most likely not issue with the file itself, since its premade asset, not something i created.

Edit

Tried it on multiple files, still nothing. Another sample code:

```
<script src="resources/three.js"></script>
<script src="resources/three.module.js"></script>
<script src="resources/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="resources/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
...
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    loader.load( 'resources/x-wing.gltf', function (gltf) {
        gltf.position.x =3;
        gltf.position.y = 0;
        gltf.position.z = -9;
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });
```

Comment: Can you seen any console errors in the developer window of your browser? Try and upload the model into here so you can figure out if it's a model problem or the code - https://threejs.org/editor/

Comment: No errors in notepad, i'm not sure how to view it in browser.

Comment: OK, depending on the browser you're using you can use a search engine to find 'show developer tools in chrome/firefox/safari/...' - Try the link I pasted too to sense-check the model you're using.

Comment: Developer tools show errors in horse.js but it is unlikely. It suggests changing : to ; in multiple places, but changing it now shows syntax errors (without suggestion what to do).

Comment: What version of `three.js` are you using? Are you aware that `THREE.LegacyJSONLoader` has been removed from the code base since `r111`?

Comment: @Mugen87 no information which one is it. Also, if LegacyJSONLoader is bad i'm open for suggestions, but as i said, different methods aren't better.

Comment: Try it with `glTF` instead. It's the recommended 3D format of the project. More information about this topic in the following guide: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

Comment: @Mugen87 can it load .js files or i need to convert it?

Comment: @Mugen87 tried this, got error - Object doesn't support this action on ```var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader()```

Comment: No, it can't load js files. I suggest you take some time and study glTF and the related code in three.js.

Comment: @Mugen87 i have converted it to gltf, but it doesn't matter here, because it fails a few rows above. Something is off about this library.

Comment: **1.** You are already loading `three.js` so you don't need `three.module.js` as well. **2.** We need more code to see how you are setting up your renderer, scene, camera, and lights. **3.** Does your code work if you replace your loader bits with defining a simple mesh, like a cube?

Comment: @TheJim01 code is fully working. Adding these lines ruins everything. I can do everything i want beside loading objects from files. After another few hours of reading it seems that it can't create instance of GLTFLoader.

Comment: Why don't you start with [a working example](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html). Be sure you have [setup correctly](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-setup.html)

Comment: Fixed it by using online resources. It isn't perfect solution, but it works.